# how to disable script error in axMozillaBrowser control c#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, mozilla, javascript

please somebody tell me how can i disable script error in axMozillaBrowser control (Mozilla ActiveX control) c#/.net

i used this code but it's not working:

`axMozillaBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`